# Separate TSQL query results in R

Tags: r, t-sql

I want to manipulate TSQL result in R. I have a query in SQL Server and I want to separate its results based on an ID column (having result of each id in one table).

Below is what I've done so far. I got the id column in R by this:

```
conn <- odbcConnect("EDW")

unformatted_id <- readLines('id.txt')

formatted_id <- gsub("\t","", paste(unformatted_id, collapse=" "))

id = sqlQuery(conn, formatted_id)
```

The id column is like this:

```
       SupplierId
1            1167
2            1831 
3             924
4            1094
5            1141
6            1198
7            1590
```

And I got my main query like this:

```
f <- function(i){
     conn <- odbcConnect("EDW")

     q = sqlQuery(conn, gsub("\t","", paste(readLines('stat.txt'), collapse=" ")))

     idd = q$id_supplier; for (i in idd) {print(q)}
}
```

With this result:

```
        id_supplier          supplier_name
1              869                       A
2              963                       B
4             1531                       C
```

But I needed the result separately: one for `id_supplier=869`, then one for `id_supplier=963` and so on.

here is my Query:

> SELECT distinct
>
> supplier.id_supplier
>
> ,supplier.name as supplier_name
>
> ,supplier.NMV AS supplier_NMV
>
> ,mean.category_bi
>
> ,mean.month
>
> ,mean.NMV AS mean_catNMv
>
> ,stat.Q1 AS Q1_catNMV
>
> ,stat.med AS med_catNMV
>
> ,stat.Q3 AS Q3_catNMV
>
> FROM supplier
>
> INNER JOIN Tier ON Tier.SupplierId=supplier.id_supplier
>
> INNER JOIN mean
>
> ON supplier.category_bi = mean.category_bi
>
> INNER JOIN stat
>
> ON stat.category_bi = mean.category_bi

Of course my `f` function doesn't do the job properly. How can I modify it?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Please format your code properly.

Comment: Please tag your RDBMS which I assume is SQL Server. Though another database, Sybase, also uses the TSQL dialect.

Comment: We need to see your SQL code which is being read in unknown .txt files.